# Cannot receive full response from Stanford NER server

Tags: python, sockets, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I need to extract named entities from thousands of Wikipedia articles in Python. I set up a Stanford NER server for that and used SocketNER from PyNER module to communicate with the server. Everything works fine if the articles are not too long. But if they are too long, the response comes fragmented and the implementation in PyNER accepts only the first packet (single socket.recv call). I tried to modify the code to receive more packets, but I could not determine which packet is the last. I thought I should look for a newline at the end of each received packet, but apparently a newline character occurs more often than just at the end of the last packet.

I also tried HttpNER, but it also fails when the texts are long.

How can I retrieve full responses from NER server?

Comment: Which server are you using? Have you tried the default server that ships with CoreNLP 3.6.0: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html ?

Comment: Also here is a wrapper for calling the server in Python: https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp